# Rails: Validate uniqueness of admin_name based off of user_name column in a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two tables: admin_users and users. I want all the created names to be unique (a regular user can't create a name already taken by an admin user and vice-versa). I'm having trouble writing a validates_uniqueness_of validation that is able to analyze information in a different table. I think I have to use a scope of some sort, but I tried all sorts of combinations and couldn't get it to work. To be clear: I'm looking for the correct code to replace the question marks below.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, :scope => #???Look in admin users 
#table and  check to make that this name is not taken.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom validator for this.

```
class UserNameValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if AdminUser.exists?(user_name: record.user_name)
      record.errors[:base] << "An admin user have this username!"
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with UserNameValidator
end
```